# Customizing Bootstrap: disabled primary button border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using the [Bootstrap template customization generator](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) to change the colours of the default states and buttons using them.

I've changed all the states correctly, but when generating a button group and using a primary button with disabled state, it is still generating a blue border which I can't seem to find an option to change in Bootstrap's generator. Code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary disabled">
    <strong>Title here</strong>
    <br><small>Hello world!</small>
</a>
```

This is generating this (note the light border compared to the button on the left which has a dark border because it is not disabled):

[image]

Inspecting the element shows this:

```
.btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover, .btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary.disabled:focus, 
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus, fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active, .btn-primary[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.disabled.active, 
.btn-primary[disabled].active, fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    background-color: #428bca; 
    border-color: #357ebd;            /* these are light blue colours */
}
```

I can't seem to find anywhere in the template generator that refers to `@btn-primary-disabled-border` or similar variations of that. I've looked through all references to `disabled` in the page and it doesn't seem to reference it.

Am I missing something somewhere or does this need to be a manual CSS override? I'd like to keep this to using Bootstrap's LESS compiler if possible.

**Edit:** [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/GbK98/) and [here's a link to my current Bootstrap definitions](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=1d05bc6d129f0a78bcc1)

Comment: is the site live? would be easier if we could look at your css

Comment: According to the sources ([1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/buttons.less#L61) -> [2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/mixins/buttons.less#L18-L34)], the disabled primary button border is set to `@btn-primary-border` value while enabled one is `darken(@btn-primary-border, 12%)`. So yes, if you need to break that tie you'll need a manual CSS override.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for that. I'm not quite grasping how I'm getting a lighter border looking through the LESS variables in my Bootstrap configuration and seeing that they are set more or less to the defaults, with my `@brand-primary` set to `#177DA0`

Comment: Yes, I see now, those colors are apparently incorrect- the strange thing is that when I compile and download the definitions you've linked to it gives me correct colors (`#177da0/#146c8a`) - not those `#428bca/#357ebd` as in your CSS. Try to recompile/redownload? (maybe you're just using some improperly "cached" zip from previous experiments?).

Comment: @seven-phases-max yeah you might be right... I'll try

Comment: Didn't seem to change it unfortunately... can you put the CSS you're getting that is correct into my fiddle?

Comment: Ah, I see what is the problem now - you're using `bootstrap-theme.css` but `bootstrap.css` should be used instead. (Honestly I never knew what's that magic "bootstrap-theme" files are doing there and what are they there for at all. Probably the customizer is supposed to produce correct "theme" files too but apparently it does not).

Comment: @seven-phases-max nice spot. Using bootstrap.css does correctly fix the borders as specified in the LESS configuration, however it also loses other features of the theme file e.g. button gradients. That fiddle you just posted still shows light blue border...? [This is a fiddle without using the `-theme.css` file](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/GbK98/2/)

Comment: OK, to correct myself, I looked at the sources and it looks like `bootstrap-theme.css` is supposed to be always used together with `bootstrap.css` - never alone (finally this is how they show it in the docs). The `theme.less` does not set the `border-color` for disabled button state at all. Now since you use only `bootstrap-theme.css` *but* also included the default `bootstrap.min.css` as an external fiddle resource, those border colors are set to the default Bootstrap color scheme. In other words, to get it right you need to put both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-theme.css` into the fiddle.

Comment: Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seven_phases_max/GDx9d/ (does not look good finally so it seems you'll still need some manual CSS fine-tuning :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max your fiddle looks a lot better... I suppose in my project that since I've only been including the theme CSS file that might be why it's appeared? Put this in an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Remove the transparent border property from your `.btn` class like below.

```
 .btn{
  border:0px solid transparent; /* this was 1px earlier */
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GbK98/6/)

Comment: Hi Suresh, [this removes the border completely](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/GbK98/1/) which means you can't see the edge of the buttons. Also the background gradient is lost... I'm looking for a LESS option if possible

Comment: Hey Suresh, you're still losing the button border completely - if I have 8 of these next to each other I want to distinguish the edges of each button...

Answer (score -1):

Use `css` style for `button`

```
<button style="border: none;" (click)="List()" type="button" class="btn-link btn-anchor">Sign up</button>
```